# No Mobile Emulation in Chrome 39.0.2171.95 m. How to enable?

Tags: google-chrome

I have Chrome 39.0.2171.95 m on Windows 7 64. But there is no Mobile Emulation in my Chrome. I have Dell Notebook 15.6 inches screen size. May small screen size be the reason? How to enable Mobile Emulation?

No **Overrides** option in my Chrome:
[image]

Chrome with **Overrides** option:

[image]

Comment: I would suspect 39 is about when they added the device mode icon along the rim of your debugger, but if you can't find it try "CTRL-SHFT-M" while in the debugger: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

Comment: @lossleader, thank you, it did the job. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks @Green, I'm glad that was the explanation and I've written it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hotkey: CTRL-SHFT-M**

To enable it with hot keys, [CTRL-SHIFT-M](http://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) should work from anywhere in the debugger and may be easier to use than looking around for the new icons as they moved around in the last few versions of Chrome.

**Finding Device Mode via the new icons in the GUI:**

In recent versions of Chrome they have moved device mode support to its own cellphone like icon:

[image: Chrome/41.0.2238.0 device mode icon]

They have also moved the Emulation Panel into submenus, toggled by the >= icon:

[image: Chrome/41.0.2238.0 submenu icon]

But the panel is only configurable when the device mode icon is already enabled.
[image: Chrome/41.0.2238.0 debug console in active emulation panel]

Note the device mode icon selected(blue) in the top left and the submenu icon selected on the top right. Though they may be in different locations in some versions.